# Do all the things have a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

I search for this but there is no answer for this question!
Do all the things have a magnetic field? And also gravity ?
Can you answer?

Comment: Where there's no current, there's no magnetic field. I'm not sure if that's your question?

Comment: In case of magnetic fields for macroscopic objects, pretty much yes, because there are always a few free spins around, but it may be very weak and very hard to measure. The case is less clear for gravity, however, searches for non-Newtonian gravity have so far not returned any modification down to a scale of 0.1mm, or so, so we can assume that every object larger than 0.1mm that is made form ordinary matter gravitates. What happens below that is experimentally unknown.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways a magnetic field can appear.

There are [permanent magnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet), and there are [electromagnets.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet)

Classically the magnetic fields of moving charges, which are how electromagnets are constructed are fully explained by Maxwell's equations.

Permanent magnets belong in the quantum mechanical regime, and are a manifestation of the underlying magnetic dipoles which all  molecular, atomic systems have, organized macroscopically so that the effect adds up.

> [In physics, mainly quantum mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_magnetic_moment) and particle physics, a spin magnetic moment is the magnetic moment induced by the spin of elementary particles. For example the electron is an elementary spin-1/2 fermion. Quantum electrodynamics gives the most accurate prediction of the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron.

In the sense that all matter is made up by elementary particles which have a spin, there are magnetic fields for all matter, but it is only if the molecules are organized that it can build up to a value to show large scale  magnetization, as with ferromagnets. For the great majority of matter the directions of individual fields from the nuclei and electrons and atoms cancel each other and one has to go to smaller than nanometer distances to see any effects.

Photons do have a magnetic field in their [wavefunction](http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002?ln=en) and build up collectively the electromagnetic field :light

> And also gravity ?

Gravity is a force of nature , not a thing, or matter. There is a hypothetical particle, [the graviton,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) which is like the photon. It is still a matter of theoretical research on how it will interact with the electromagnetic field.  One expects that there will be an effect due to higher order Feynman diagrams. We have not seen isolated gravitons, much less studied their properties.

Answer (score 1):

Everything does actually have a magnetic field...  But only at a microscopic/atomic level. 
Consider the fact that electrons are present in the atoms and are constantly revolving around the nucleus...  This in turn leads to a kind of magnetic field generated at the atomic level. But all these magnetic moments due to each electron are oriented randomly in all directions (I am not really sure why...) and hence on the macroscopic scale no magnetic field is usually felt.